# multiprocessing multiple executors waiting for each job

Tags: python

I have 2 tasks - load_url and some_job. Need to submit both in parallel and using python executors...

Looks like the executor doesn't start - some_job - until it finishes load_url.

When I run this job - some_job is started only after the load_url process is finished.

```
import sys
from concurrent import futures
import urllib.request
import multiprocessing
import time

URLS = ['http://www.foxnews.com/',
        'http://www.cnn.com/',
        'http://europe.wsj.com/',
        'http://www.bbc.co.uk/',
        'http://some-made-up-domain.com/']


def load_url(url, e, timeout=0):
    # it will take 10 seconds to process a URL
    time.sleep(10)
    return None

def some_job(url, e, timeout=0):
    print('some_job')
    time.sleep(10)
    return None


def check_futures(livefutures):
    runningfutures = True
    while runningfutures:
            runningfutures = [f for f in livefutures if f.running()]
            print('runningfutures=', runningfutures)


def main():
    print('start')
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    e = manager.Event()
    t = '1'
    with futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
        livefutures = dict(
            (executor.submit(load_url, url, e), url)
            for url in URLS)

        test = executor.submit(some_job, t, e)
        print('check_futures')
        # runningfutures = True
        check_futures(livefutures)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Are you sure you want `t='1'`?

Comment: nope, that's just passing some dummy parameters.